# Why is the Correctve Smooth modifier different when saved as a Shape Key

Tags: modifiers, rigging, shape-keys

I am trying to understand something:
I have tried to use a Corrective Smooth modifier to fix some deformation. It works very well. I want to be able to save that shape though, to be able to use it outside Blender as well. For that I tried to apply or save the modifier as a Shape Key. It helps a bit, but the resulting shape is different from the modifier. I tried to fiddle around with the setting of the modifier before applying, but no luck so far. Can anybody help? :)

Corrective Smooth modifier Working as intended:
[image: Corrective Smooth modifier Working as intended]

Applying as Shape Key (I tried saving too, same results):
[image: applying as Shape Key]

Without the Shape Key or modifier:
[image: without the Shape Key or modifier]

With the saved/applied Shape Key:
(better, but not the same as the live modifier)
[image: with the saved/applied Shape Key]

Comment: I would expect that after applying the modifier as Shapekey, it should retain its. The only reason I can think of is that it has something to do with the armature modifier. But even so, theoretically, it should still work. I will experiment and see if I can find why that happens.

Comment: As I feared, I guess the armature modifier is the culprit. The only workaround for me was to create a shapekey and manually adjust the mesh using the sculpting tools. Perhaps there are other ways anyone else might know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing here is the order of the modifiers.  The corrective smooth is acting on the armature-deformed positions, because it is after the armature, but you can't apply modifiers out-of-order.  When you apply a modifier, Blender always moves to the modifier to the top of the stack to apply it (and gives you a warning saying it is doing so.)

The other potential issue here, not the main issue, is with a corrective smooth on original coords-- if you apply modifiers in order, you'll be changing the original coords.  Using bind coords, even if bound to original coords, is usually wise in cases where you want to apply corrective smooth modifiers.

What you need to do to get this to work is to armature deform, corrective smooth, and then *un*-armature deform, and get that final mesh as your shapekey.  This isn't impossible, but it's a lot of work without any scripting or addons.  You'd bind the corrective smooth to original coords, apply the armature, apply the bound corrective smooth, armature deform from the "apply as rest pose" version of that armature, and set that armature's deforming bones to copy transforms from the original, unposed armature.  All armature modifiers would need to be set to "preserve volume".

Typically when people want to work with these kind of corrective shapekeys, they use the corrective shapekeys addon, bundled with Blender, to make their job easier.  It does the job of doing the armature deform-> undo armature steps for you.

Comment: I will try that, thanks :)